# Monotouch: arrange the UINavigationController back button in a different position

Tags: xamarin.ios

How can I arrange (programatically) the back button of a UINavigationController in a different position?
For example, suppose that the back button (visible in the upper bar of a UINavigationController) has these coordinates: 67 for x and 10 for y. I would arrange the back button for these coordinates: 89 for x and 10 for y.
Do I have to override these measures in a specific method (for example viewDidLoad() method)?

Thank you. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this cannot be done in a simple way as you can manipulate the navigation bar only via few properties. So there are basically two methods:

1) traverse the UI tree and search for the actual button control created by iOS for you in the navigation toolbar and change its Frame property. You can always get to the inner controls by the Subviews property, so call navigationController.Subviews and iterate through that until you find the control you would like to move, btw it could be deep in the hierarchy, depends. And with iOS update this can change, so this is a bit of a hack, but usually such technique works well.

2) do the custom way. Hide the actual navigation bar, and do the navigation yourself via custom buttons, add a UIButton to your interface, in the action for that call popViewController on the navigationController. If you're inside a view controller, you can use this.navigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated (...);

If you need nice buttons, use this PSD, works well for me http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Hope this helps. If so, please vote.